# Why do flags become "aged away"?

Tags: discussion, flags

A couple of my flags got the status "aged away".

Why are some flags reviewed very quickly, and some got the status "aged away"?

Do flags have some priority list?

Or maybe  not very important flags become "aged away"?

Comment: They age away if they are no reviewed by reviewer(s) within the expiration limit

Comment: Why sometimes new flags get reviewed sooner then the old pending flags?

Comment: Pure luck. People reviewed your newer flags while they didn't review your older flags.

Comment: Don't worry about a couple of flags. I got 123 aged away flags [myself](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4029561?group=1&status=5)

Comment: @cromagnon besides luck, speed also depends on the type of flag and which queue it goes into. Flags like Not an Answer and Very Low Quality go into the Low Quality Posts queue, which moves very quickly. But flags that fall under "should be closed" go into the Close Vote Review queue, which moves slowly due to the volume.

Comment: @NSNoob no one can access that link apart from yourself or moderators...

Comment: @JonClements Ohhh. I always assumed that wasn't the case. Thanks